# Radiobutton behavior Android Studio

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Simple problem to fix (I hope)...can't figure it out myself though.
I need one radio button to be un-checked or un-selected when the other is checked/selected.

Here is my code. Right now the app works fine but when the user goes to change the selection the first button doesn't clear:

```
Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        weightEntered=Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat tenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

        if (lbToKilo.isChecked()) {
            if (weightEntered <= 500) {
                convertedWeight = weightEntered / conversionRate;
                result.setText(tenth.format(convertedWeight) + " kilograms");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pounds must be less than 500.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        if (kiloToLb.isChecked()) {
            if (weightEntered <= 225) {
                convertedWeight = weightEntered * conversionRate;
                result.setText(tenth.format(convertedWeight) + " pounds");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kilos must be less than 225.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to group your RadioButtons in a `RadioGroup`.
That's all you need to get some `mutually exclusive` RadioButtons.

For your reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html